# Wordpress on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wordpress

I tried installing wordpress on ubuntu. I followed the steps in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial literally verbatim.

It gives the error "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress." when I gave url

```
http://localhost/nkm/
```

and it gives me just the apache server page on giving

```
http://localhost/
```

I can't trace this error to its source. Could this community help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install `php5-mysql` package

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```